# How to restore Site Collection from one environment to another

Tags: powershell, restore

I am developing my intranet portal in office and created the same environment at home even the domain name and the users I am working with.

I have taken the backup of site collection through central admin (dont remember if I have selected with security or without) but I did and it created a .bak file.

Later I came home and I went into central admin, created a web application and tried restoring the site using cmdlet.

> Restore-SPSite -identity http://mycompany -path
>   "D:\PortalBackup\MyCompanySiteBackup.bak"

After typing Y in Yes it started restoring...but when I tried accessing the site by http://mycompany

It's giving me unexpected error.  I guess there are permission issues.

Please guide what are the steps I should take to restore site collection from one environment to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you deployed any customisations to the farm in your office? They'll need redeploying in your home environment.

Comment: nahhh no customization...the environment is ditto.

Comment: Even the 3 service accounts I am using there are also being created in home environment. is it something with the content database and the users associated with it? I even turned on the customErrorMode in inetpub 80 app but not showing the exact error even after iisreset

Comment: Ok, try using the `Export-SPSite` Powershell cmdlet rather than backing up in Central Admin. Restore-SPSite is designed to work with the products of Export-SPSite rather than backups.

Comment: you mean to say this way ? http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/09/21/use-sharepoint-2010-powershell-cmdlets-to-get-and-manage-sites.aspx

Comment: Yup exactly. Give that a blast. It's used on my current project to ensure all developers have latest versions of the site content as it's being authored. Works rather well.

Comment: I've tried with the same .bak (through central admin) but it didnt work so I guess i will have to Export-SPWeb through cmdlet again from office environement and give it a try...will update as soon as I will reach office. but james tell me one thing...this export thingy will also set the home environment database security settings exactly as office environment database and their users also or do i need to manually set it on content database?

Comment: It'll set all the security to how it is in your office. So if the site collection admin for the office one is domain\admin1 and you don't have a domain called 'domain' in your home, you'll ahve to reset the site collection admin at home. This would be the first thing to check if you get 'access denied' when you try to load your newly restored site at home.

Comment: james thanks....lovely...will check and revert back as i am off for two days...

Comment: James I've accepted your answer ..thanks to everyone who added valuable comments and made me backup the subsites.

Answer (score 0):

If your site collection was restored correctly, if it is really permission issue, you can try to give you permissions of site collection administrator through the central administration. Anyway it is usually enough to get site collection backup by Backup-SPSite and restore it by Restore-SPSite, if you don't have permissions after that, just give it yourself in central administration.

Comment: Well ive tried restoring through Import-SPWeb but it imported only the root site which is HOME. The "About Us" site was created as subsite which is not imported as it says "Import-SPWeb : The file  cannot be imported because its parent /AboutUs does no
t exist."

Please guide how to take backup of Parent and subsites also or do I need to take backup at individual level like HOME, then About US then Departments then Depart A, Department B and so on....

Comment: As I know there are no possibility to grab all webs in one piece by Import-SPWeb, but there are some options in SharePoint content deployment to grab child sites with parent. Read little bit about that, may be it will be helpful for you. Check this post as a starting point http://khdraft.blogspot.ru/2011/04/sharepoint-content-deployment_10.html/ There is C# code, but you also can implement it using PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

After you restore in another environment... Try to change the site collection administrator... As it may be a problem... if you are on a different environment...

Comment: Hi Paddy, this would server better as a comment on the question. If it is the correct answer you can either make this answer more verbose now, or after the effect.